# Can revoked SSL certificate be renewed?

Tags: ssl, tls1.2, lets-encrypt, auto-renewing, certbot

So I was using Certbot to automatically renew the Let's Encrypt TLS certificate via --webroot and crontab.

The question is:

> Can a TLS/SSL certificate be renewed **just as usual** if it is revoked for some Unforeseeable reason?

Or do I have to apply for a brand new certificate.

Comment: Some unforeseeable reason such as what? The major reason to revoke a certificate would be that the private key had leaked, and you certainly wouldn't want to renew it in that circumstance, you would want to re-key and start again.

Comment: Such as leaked private key and bad jokers. Why wouldn't I want to use the renewed one? The renewed one's private key isn't leaked. Would there be something wrong down the chain?

Comment: A certificate renewal uses the same private key as the one being renewed, by definition.

Comment: Jeez, then what is the point of renewing, why not re-key every time?

Comment: There's no great reason in my view for rekeying if the key hasn't been compromised, but no doubt many people do exactly that.

Comment: Oh well, if I check validity and renew, that'll be few bash script lines more, I guess I'll just rekey then. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4):

The revocation is done for a certificate with a specific serial number. A renewal would issue a new certificate with a different serial number. This means that the existing revocation would not apply to the new certificate even if all other parts of the certificate were kept unchanged.

Since a revocation is usually done if the private key of the certificate was compromised somehow or if the owner of the domain changed, you should make sure that the renewed certificate is not created with the old private key, i.e. not reuse the old certificate signing request but create a new one with a new private key (rekeying).

Comment: So if the guy who stole the old private key renewed the revoked certificate, the renewed revoked certificate won't appear to have any problems? Or the rekeying process make the original private key related certs invalid(one domain can only have one valid certificate)?

Comment: @WenkHsueh: If somebody else can create  a publicly trusted certificate for your domain (this includes renewing) then you are in deep trouble, no matter if the one has your private key or not. And having the private key of the certificate is not enough to renew the certificate - but it is enough to use the existing certificate inside attacks. And renewing a certificate does not necessarily invalid all previous certificates for the domain - if you want this then make sure that your CA does this.